# Spring MVC 3.1.3 : Is there a way to use Async Support in spring mvc versions below 3.2?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way i can use the `Servlet 3` based asynchronous request processing in Spring version below `Spring mvc 3.2` ?

Comment: why not use use java for asynch programming.may be you could message brokers like rabbitmq.

Comment: No i want to use Asynchnous request processing in my DWP